# google app script throwing error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am receiving the following `error`:

> "Service using too much computer time for one day"

How many times does the google script allowed to execute/ day? Is there any work around for this, it is require for me to run the script every minute.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the script and what are you running it in? Some calls are limited more than others. Please post more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you get daily limits. Currently, the triggers max total run time is set at 90 min / day. The workaround would be to make your script execute faster. Considering there are 1440 minutes in a day, your script should run under 3.75 seconds for your trigger to work.

[Here are some tips](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices) from Google Developers to help you make your code run faster. For example, batching operations can reduce runtime by 98.6 %.

Please, could you let me know if that solution was applicable to you?